# Razor syntax to render section based on condition

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I got a view with Layout defined.  In the layout, there is a section:

`@RenderSection("JavaScript", required: false)`

In the view, based on a condition, I want to either render certain JavaScript to the section or not.

```
@if (condition)
{ 
    @section JavaScript
    {
        <script type="text/javascript>
           $(document).ready(function(){
             //bla...
           });
        </script>
    }
}
```

The above syntax is wrong.  What's the correct syntax?

### Edit

Basically, I got a partial view which needs to be rendered based on a condition.  If the condition is true, then I need to render the partial view together with some JavaScript for the partial view, which I want to go to the "JavaScript" section.  How can I do that?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

`@section` blocks can only appear in markup contexts.

You can write

```
@if (condition)
{ 
    <text>
        @section JavaScript
        {
            <script type="text/javascript>
               $(document).ready(function(){
                 //bla...
               });
            </script>
        }
    </text>
}
```

Comment: You can also use a comment to change the markup context, so that you don't need a spurious tag, ie. 
@if (condition) { <!-- Comment here --> \@section JavaScript

Comment: @Deeksy: `<text>` is a Razor tag; it is not emitted in the output.

Answer (score 2):

@if(condition) RenderSection(..)

```
@Section Javascript{ 
        <script type="text/javascript>
           $(document).ready(function(){
             //bla...
           });
        </script>
}
```

or in your layout:

```
@RenderSection(..)
```

and in your view:

```
@section Javascript{ 
if(condition) 
{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            //bla...
        });
    </script>
} 
}
```

also see:
[Is there a way to make a @section optional with the asp.net mvc Razor ViewEngine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4903289/is-there-a-way-to-make-a-section-optional-with-the-asp-net-mvc-razor-viewengine)

Comment: Is this inside of the Layout?  The layout doesn't know about the condition.

Comment: then your condition is inside of your section as opposed to the other way around that you have up top.

Comment: Ok.  Essentially, I have a condition inside the view.  If it's true, I need to render a partial view together with some JavaScript for the partial view. So, on the view level, how can I specify to either render the section or not?

Comment: In the view simply have @if(condition){RenderSection(....)}     or are you referring to something else?

Comment: RenderSection(....) is a line of code inside of Layout.   @section SectionName{....} is code inside of view.  Putting RenderSection() in view results in The file "~/Views/MyView/Bla.cshtml" cannot be requested directly because it calls the "RenderSection" method.  Your example has a condition inside of Layout.  I need to have that condition inside of View.  Or am I not getting something?

Comment: ah I see your structure. Your condition must either be passed to the layout to use (viewbag or see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5973208/net-mvc3-getting-a-reference-to-the-page-from-a-controller/5973573#comment-6902117    )   or your bla.cshtml must have that condition inside of the @section declaration . I'll edit answer above to show