# Declaring sections within code

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Trying to create code section within an If condition throws error:
Unexpected "section" keyword after "@" character. Once inside code, you do not need to prefix constructs like "section" with "@".

```
Example 1:Create section when needed
@If bIsMobile = True Then
@section PageFooter
    <div data-role="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Add</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Edit</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Delete</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Search</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Refresh</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
End Section
End If
```

Obviously we could move the condition inside the section, but this forces processing of empty section blocks:

```
Example 2:Creates empty section
@section PageFooter
@If bIsMobile = True Then
    <div data-role="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Add</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Edit</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Delete</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Search</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Refresh</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
End If
End Section
```

How can we implement Example #1

Comment: I don't know what more clarity you need than "Once inside code, you do not need to prefix constructs like "section" with "@"."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@section blocks can only appear in markup context. Thanks to [SLacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5982636/razor-syntax-to-render-section-based-on-condition) for this answer.

```
@If bIsMobile = True Then
<text>
   @section PageFooter
     <div data-role="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Add</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Edit</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Delete</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Search</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Refresh</a></li>
        </ul>
     </div>
   End Section
</text>
End If
```

And check in _Layout page whether section is defined for non mobile pages. Otherwise it will throw an exception stating that the “PageFooter” section wasn’t defined.

```
<footer>
  @If IsSectionDefined("PageFooter") Then
      RenderSection("PageFooter")
  End If
</footer>
```

Comment: Thank you for the example! Now I understand, great help.

Answer (score 0):

The second example that you gave is the correct one.

As far as I know you can't specify to the razor engine to include a section in a conditional or loop block.