# The following sections have been defined but have not been rendered for the layout page with one line conditional

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor, razor-pages

I am getting the error below but I have it defined on the Layout page below. I changed the `@(IsSectionDefined` to `@if(IsSectionDefined` because I need to write `null` in the `else` statement.  Why would this be an issue?

```
The following sections have been defined but have not been rendered for the layout page "~/Areas/Directors/Views/Shared/_MembersFormLayout.cshtml": "FormCallback".
```

**Layout.cshtml**

```
 <form data-bind="form:{ id: @Model.FormId, callback: @if (IsSectionDefined("FormCallback")){RenderSection("FormCallback", false);}else {@(Html.Raw("null"))}}">
```

**Page.cshtml**

```
@section FormCallback{members.event.updateImage}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix it with his helper function found at [Is there a way to make a @section optional with the asp.net mvc Razor ViewEngine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4903289/is-there-a-way-to-make-a-section-optional-with-the-asp-net-mvc-razor-viewengine)
.

```
<form class="clearfix" action="@Request.RawUrl" data-bind="form:{ id: @Model.FormId, callback: @this.RenderSection("FormCallback", @<text>null</text>)}">

public HelperResult RenderSection(string name, Func<dynamic, HelperResult> defaultContents)
{
    if (IsSectionDefined(name))
    {
        return RenderSection(name);
    }
    return defaultContents(null);
}
```